# Animation is not playing because of a child object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I animated a shooting animation for my character and his weapon; the weapon is a child of an empty thats a child to a hand bone. Whenever I animate a transform on the weapon the animation will not play and the character cannot move. I tried my best to describe the situation, sorry if the solution is simple.

I tried other animations to see what was causing it for sure, and I didn't have the same problem unless it was this one, which the child object is animated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: This takes place in the animator tab, no code is involved.